# Graph Explorer: HTTP 401 Response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for testing a query against `OneNote` from office 365.

I am using a sample query example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages
```

But I am getting and error :

`Status Code 401 - Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.`

I have checked the permission and `Notes.ReadWrite.All` is checked.

[image]

refer below screenshot :

[image]
[image]

Is there any other settings that I might need to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Admin Consent in order to use `Notes.ReadWrite.All`. There is a link that an Admin from the tenant needs to follow to enable these permissions at the bottom of the Modify Permissions dialog:

[image]

Comment: @Mark Thanks for you reply. Today I check again the same query and it started working automatically. Previously I was trying to access the OneNote immediately after making changes in permissions(through Administrator account). I guess it takes some time to reflect the changes in permission. That's why I was getting above error. :)